# How can you transfer saved game black ops online to same PS3 but diff account?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops

I tried it and it say "the save data was created by another user and cannot be used. Select OK to select save data to delete or press the PS button to quit."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not do this without a save resign because the saves are assigned to your specific account so without resigning the save no it is not at all possible

Comment: why the heck did i get a downvote for a correct answer like wtf

Answer (score 0):

The online data is attached to the account. The game save file and the online profile are two different things.

The one you can copy to another account is the game save file, which saves progress in the campaign mode only.

The online profile (your progress in the online multiplayer mode) is saved in the PlayStation Network account (online, in the cloud, like your avatar is), you cannot copy that and don't need to, if you sign in on another PlayStation device all your customizations, weapons, and all you've done online will be right there.